# Using vb.net to display a form inside a panel. error transparency

Tags: vb.net

I have a panel and button.
A form with some text-box.
Trying to display form inside my panel. code that i have written is....

```
 Private Sub Btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn.Click

   Dim f As New form()
    f.TopLevel = False
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    f.Visible = True
    Pages.Controls.Add(f)
  End Sub
```

in another page, i have written.....

```
Dim f As New add_customer()
    f.TopLevel = False
    f.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
    f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
    f.Visible = True
    Form1.Pages.Controls.Add(f)
```

Form displays inside panel. Button inside that form works well, Combo-box works well, Check-box works well, all most everything works well, but text-box isn't working.
Tried that form to open outside panel. All is fine. But inside panel it doesn't work.
All the letters and text-box become transparent.
Main form
[image]
After Customer button clicked
[image]
After add customer button clicked
[image]
When pages run solely....
[image]
[image]
Help needed.

Comment: If you only plan to use these in a control and not as standalone forms then using a [**`UserControl`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol(v=vs.90).aspx) would be better.

Comment: It has to be done inside panel. Moreover it displays the form. But I don't know why am I getting error.

Comment: Yes, but I meant if you plan to show the forms as standalone forms, and not only as embedded controls. Because if you don't then you should just replace the forms with UserControls. As for the problem: What's the forms' `TransparencyKey` property set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution.

When the TransparencyKey property is assigned a Color, the areas of the form that have the same BackColor will be displayed transparently. Any mouse actions, such as the click of the mouse, that are performed on the transparent areas of the form will be transferred to the windows below the transparent area. For example, if the client region of a form is made transparent, clicking the mouse on that area would send the event notification of the click to any window that is below it. If the color assigned to the TransparencyKey property is the same as any controls on the form, they also will be displayed transparently.

I was unaware of this property of Transparency.
I Have changed background colour and all is good now.
Thanks Visual Vincent for your fast reply.....

This link is useful.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx